# React Native Data Passing in Material Top Tabs Navigator

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-native-router-flux, react-navigation-top-tabs

I create a `EventCard` on press the card `Event Details` page open, where there is details of events shown. In details there is Event `Organizer` details. By press on `Organizer`, `Organizer Profile` page open. Where Organizer details are shown.

`Organizer Button`

```
<TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate("OrganizerProfile", { item: item })}>
          <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', }}>
            <Image
              style={{ height: 48, width: 48, borderRadius: 12, }}
              source={item.organizerDp}
            />
            <View style={{ marginLeft: 14 }}>
              <Text style={{ color: '#120D26', fontSize: 16, fontWeight: '400', lineHeight: 34, }}>{item.organizer}</Text>
              <Text style={{ color: '#747688', fontSize: 12, fontWeight: '400', }}>Organizer</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

`Organizer Profile`

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, Image, ScrollView, TouchableHighlight, FlatList } from 'react-native'
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs';
import OrganizerAbout from './OrganizerAbout';
import OrganizerEvents from './OrganizerEvents';
import OrganizerReviews from './OrganizerReviews';

const OrganizerProfile = ({ route }) => {
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();
    const { item } = route.params;
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#fff' }}>
        Header...
        Profile Pic...
        Name...
        Follower...
        Buttons...
            <View style={{ alignItems: 'center', marginTop: 10, flex: 1, marginHorizontal: 24 }}>
                <Tab.Navigator
                    screenOptions={{
                        styling...
                    }}
                >
                    <Tab.Screen
                        name="About"
                        component={OrganizerAbout}
                    />
                    <Tab.Screen 
                    name="Event" 
                    component={OrganizerEvents} 
                    />
                    <Tab.Screen
                        name="Reviews"
                        component={OrganizerReviews}
                    />
                </Tab.Navigator>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}
export default OrganizerProfile
```

`Organizer DB`

```
const upcomingEventsInfo = [
    {
        id: 1,
        others...
        organizer: 'Ashfak Sayem',
        organizerFollowing: '200',
        organizerFollowers: '457',
        organizerAbout: 'Enjoy your favorite dishe and a lovely your friends and family and have a great time.',
        organizerReviews: {
            reviewPic: require("../Assets/ReviewsProfilePics/Pic1.png"),
            reviewName: "Rocks Velkeinjen",
            reviewDay: "10",
            reviewMonth: "Feb",
            reviewComment: "Cinemas is the ultimate experience to see new movies in Gold Class or Vmax. Find a cinema near you."
        },
        organizerDp: require("../Assets/OrganizerPics/OrganizerDp1.png"),
        others...
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        others...
        organizer: 'Emma Amelia',
        organizerFollowing: '250',
        organizerFollowers: '507',
        organizerAbout: 'About Emma Amelia About Emma Amelia About Emma Amelia About Emma Amelia About Emma Amelia',
        organizerReviews: {
            reviewPic: require("../Assets/ReviewsProfilePics/Pic1.png"),
            reviewName: "Rocks Velkeinjen",
            reviewDay: "10",
            reviewMonth: "Feb",
            reviewComment: "Cinemas is the ultimate experience to see new movies in Gold Class or Vmax. Find a cinema near you."
        },
        organizerDp: require("../Assets/OrganizerPics/OrganizerDp2.png"),
        others...
    },
```

When I access Organizer data in organizer details page its working, But when I access it in top tab navigator `About tab` it dont show the `organizerAbout` data related to Organizer.